# unknown variable 'bind-address=ip'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was trying to run some `mysql` command, but then when I run it, this happens

```
mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address=[ip]'
```

Stuff looks different in `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = [ip]
port = 3306
```

`50-server.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

bind-address = [ip]
```

`mysql.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
bind-address = [ip]
port = 3306
```

`ps -aux | grep mysql`:

```
mysql     4171  0.7  3.1 730344 96612 ?        Ssl  15:54   0:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Comment: put something like: bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

Comment: @jet I already put my IP in, but the command is probably reading off of something else. `[ip]` is just an example, the real content has a legit IP.

Comment: Delete that line in the file and type it by hand.

Comment: Code below should work. As bind-address is related to the daemon add [mysqld] above your bind-address parameter.
`[mysqld]`

`bind-address = ip_here`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `bind-address` option for `mysql` in MariaDB. This option is related to the daemon part `mysqld`.

So remove the `bind-address` from your `[mysql]` section in the `mysql.cnf` file.

Comment: Mmm... I don't know. In order to get work the remote connections, Maria DB needs to the "bind-adress" option to listen al ipv4 address, see this docs https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/database-guides/how-enable-remote-access-your-mariadbmysql-database

Comment: Do not remove it but put it inside a section for server only, like [mysqld]

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, I wanted to work in the client mariadb or mysql of the terminal and in the client dbeaver, so I had to add this lines in this file /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

It is important to add the label [mysqld], if you don´t add only works in dbeaver and it doesn´t work in the client mariadb. Adding this label works in both.

Remember reset the service to apply the changes.

```
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

Use the command of the terminal mysql or mariadb to use these clients

```
mysql

mariadb
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!